# How can I pull blade views from my Laravel app and display them through my WordPress app?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a WordPress plugin which provides such integration. One example of what I am trying to achieve is pulling the job postings from my Laravel application and display them as a section in one of my WordPress website pages. Both the Laravel and WordPress databases sit differently.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the page in an iframe in your post... point to a route that returns only what you want in Laravel...

```
<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/wordpressjobs"></iframe>
```

Create a route for wordpressjobs and return only the html you wish to embed...